# I need a regex to match numbers between brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code in c#:

```
   MatchCollection ids;
   ids = Regex.Matches(oldJoinClause, "\\[([0-9]{*})\\]");
```

And i'm trying to match this: [881]%1.[2949] = [734]%2.[3551]

The regex works if i write an amount of number i want between the brackets like {3} so i'll get 881 and 734. But the length can be bigger or smaller and i don't know how to match any amount of numbers.

I've read on regex that you have to use * or .* or d+ or + i've tried everything and nothing works if i don't put a number between those {}.

I've also tried to do something like this: \[([/d+])\] or just leave as \[([0-9])\] but same result.

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: Remove `{` and `}` and use `"\\[([0-9]*)\\]"` or `@"\[([0-9]+)]"`. `*` matches zero or more occurrences, `+` matches 1 or more occurrences.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, thank you mate :D

Comment: You need a regex like this `\\[\\d*\\]`: